# Why sometimes ftp_nlist returns empty array while there is file inside folder?

Tags: php, ftp

I'm using `ftp_put` to upload file on the FTP server.
Right after `ftp_put` I use `ftp_nlist` to fetch list of uploaded files. The weird thing is **sometimes** `ftp_nlist` returns empty array while there are files in the target FTP directory.
What can cause this problem?

Update 1:

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $ftpdir.$file, $localdir.'/'.$file, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Successfully uploaded $file.<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Error uploading $file.<br/>";
    }
}
$files = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, $ftpdir);
print("<pre>".print_r($files,true)."</pre>");
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to show a little more of your PHP code, please?

Comment: @billy.farroll Sure. You can see the code now.

Comment: So, does this sometimes work and other times it doesn't? Even though there are files in the FTP directory?

Comment: @billy.farroll. Yes. Exactly. Sometime it does work and return files list. But sometime it doesn't work and return null while there are files in the FTP folder.

Comment: So how do you check *"there are files in the FTP folder"*?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I can see "Successfully uploaded $file." message as I wrote and on the other hand I check existence of files through directadmin.I'm sure files are uploaded there but I don't know why ftp_nlist returns null.

Comment: Can you see the files using any FTP client? (nothing else matters)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes I can see the uploaded fiiles trough FTP as well. Actually this script runs continuous. Download file(s) -> Upload them -> get list of uploaded files -> insert file list into database | Download next file(s) and so on. Sometimes it returns null.But if I check that specific nulled returned directory with ftp_nlist again it return files list. I dont know what is happening in the meantime!

Comment: Do you have an access to FTP server log file? Or if you login with some FTP client and keep refreshing the folder, does it also fail sometime?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes I have access to FTP server logs. When I keep refreshing with FTP client it never fails.

Comment: So can you post FTP log for a successful and failing `ftp_nlist`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - I think `ftp_nlist` doesn't pass any log to the server. But I can see directory creation and file upload log.
`51.xx UNKNOWN xxxxx [05/Jun/2018:11:14:30 +0000] "MKD /public_html/ftpdir/folder1/2018-01-08/" 257` `51.xx UNKNOWN xxxxx [05/Jun/2018:11:14:43 +0000] "STOR /public_html/ftpdir/folder1/file.ext" 226 46956472`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - I was trying to get list of files using `ftp_nlist` after uploading a file for several times. Every time an empty array returned. But when I closed FTP connection and reconnect it right before fetching files list it worked.I dont know it will work always or not!